# Error: Incorrect usage of UNION and ORDER BY

Tags: mysql-5.5, mysqli

I have this query:

```
SELECT DISTINCT CONCAT (MONTH(`Date`),'-',YEAR(`Date`)) 
from wp_result_plugin 
WHERE Bet=2 
AND month(`Date`) = EXTRACT(month FROM (NOW())) 
ORDER BY MONTH(`Date`) ASC

UNION 

SELECT DISTINCT CONCAT (MONTH(`Date`),'-',YEAR(`Date`)) 
from wp_result_plugin 
WHERE Bet=2 
AND month(`Date`) 
ORDER BY MONTH(`Date`) ASC
```

I am seeing this error:

```
Incorrect usage of UNION and ORDER BY
```

How to make this work?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Wrap the selects into parentheses

```
(SELECT DISTINCT CONCAT (MONTH(`Date`),'-',YEAR(`Date`)) from wp_result_plugin WHERE Bet=2 AND month(`Date`) = EXTRACT(month FROM (NOW())) ORDER BY MONTH(`Date`) ASC )
UNION 
(SELECT DISTINCT CONCAT (MONTH(`Date`),'-',YEAR(`Date`)) from wp_result_plugin WHERE Bet=2 AND month(`Date`) ORDER BY MONTH(`Date`) ASC)
```

Comment: @zugguy thank you man this jot me what i needed just one more thing can i make this in to a single query

Comment: Well to tell you the truth, I didn't actually study your queries before and now that I did, they are strange; month(`Date`) is always != 0 so this part: AND month(`Date`) in second query is superfluous; also, you likely have more than one row with same values for month(`Date`) so your order by clauses will not produce deterministic results... perhaps you could give the structure of wp_result_plugin table and explain what you're trying to do and I might have a suggestion?